# `DateTime.strptime` mysteriously add one hour to the inputted time

Tags: jquery-ui, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I used Jquery datetime picker to pass time as text to the controllers:

```
Parameters: {"assignment"=>{"deadline"=>"08/29/2014 09:00"}}
```

In `assignments_controller.rb`, I parse the params as follow (my `config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`:

```
@assignment.deadline = DateTime.strptime(params[:assignment][:deadline] + " Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z").in_time_zone
```

But somehow, when `@assignment.save`, the following is recorded in database:

```
UPDATE "assignments" SET "deadline" = ? WHERE "assignments"."id" = 9  [["deadline", Fri, 29 Aug 2014 10:00:00 EDT -04:00]]
```

So, even though in params, deadline is 9 AM, in Active record it is 10. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out: It's due to daylight saving time. The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100456/rails-daylight-savings-time-not-accounted-for-when-using-datetime-strptime) lead to to create a helper method:

```
  def parse_time_with_correct_zone(input_string)
    input_format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
    datetime_with_wrong_zone = DateTime.strptime(input_string, input_format)
    correct_datetime = Time.zone.parse(datetime_with_wrong_zone.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    correct_datetime
  end
```

Then I just use this method in controller instead of `DateTime.strptime`.

Comment: This code worked for me. Thanks. Only difference is that my input_format includes %p for am/pm. 

It's 2018 and this is still the best solution to a common problem. Wish a similar could be pulled into the DateTime or Time classes. I'm taking user specified time ranges and submitting them to an AWS API that requires GMT epoch time.